# Error: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations

I got a Laravel MySQL migration problem.

Migration:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('capsule_packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->tinyInteger('type')->unsigned();
        $table->json('data')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('price', 19, 4);
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json null, `price` decimal(19, 4) not null, `description` text null, `created_at' at line 1 (SQL: create table`capsule_packages`(`id`int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,`name`varchar(255) not null,`type`tinyint unsigned not null,`data`json null,`price`decimal(19, 4) not null,`description`text null,`created_at`timestamp null,`updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_unicode_ci')

Comment: that migration code works fine for me.  running 10.2.20-MariaDB-1:10.2.20+maria~bionic

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which exact part is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to your `MySQL` version. Did some digging around, and seems like since Laravel 5.2, the `$table->json()` method will try to create an actual `json` field in the database. But, in your example, the `json` ins't available in your current MySQL version. You can use this field only from MySQL version `5.7.8.` and higher. If you're using version that's lower than this, you can resolve this error by creating a `text` field, instead of `json`.

You can see this in you error code:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server **version** for the right syntax to use near **json**

Source: [dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-json)

EDIT:

As per `MariaDB` version `10.1.x` and lower does not support `json` data type

Source: [github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13622](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13622)

Comment: I am using MySQL. It is the json format problem. It work pretty well if I change json to text.